# Model.fit tensorflow Issue

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, model

model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=128, epochs=30)
i am using this and i got this error
Epoch 1/30

### Output exceeds the size limit. Open the full output data in a text editor

UnimplementedError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_1768\4221927022.py in 
----> 1 model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=128, epochs=30)

c:\Users\decil\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
68             # To get the full stack trace, call:
69             # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70             raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
71         finally:
72             del filtered_tb

c:\Users\decil\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
50   try:
51     ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 52     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
53                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
54   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:

UnimplementedError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'sequential/Cast' defined at (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\decil\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
File "c:\Users\decil\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
...
File "c:\Users\decil\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\functional.py", line 762, in _conform_to_reference_input
tensor = tf.cast(tensor, dtype=ref_input.dtype)
Node: 'sequential/Cast'
Cast string to float is not supported
[[{{node sequential/Cast}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_529]

Please help me in this issue

Comment: "Cast string to float is not supported" Make sure your training data does not contain strings, it must be all numerical.

Answer (score 0):

I see the problem is here `Cast string to float is not supported`  basically you're trying to pass a string (maybe the labels?) when the model expects a number (float). But I don't have enough info to help you any further.